# Insert Columns with matching values

Tags: r, match

I have two Data frames. The first one is jobs:

```
Jobs <- data.frame(Company = c("A","B"), Name = c("Peter","Peter"), Job = c("CEO","Member of the Board"))
```

The Second one is Media_Appearence:

```
Media_Appearence <- data.frame(Company = c("A","A","B","B","A","A","A","A"),Name = c("Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter"))
```

Is there any way, using basic R commands,to insert a new column on Media_Appearence filling it using matching arguments (Checking First two columns anda returning the matching job) ? The desired output would be:

```
Media_Appearence <- data.frame(Company = c("A","A","B","B","A","A","A","A"),Name = c("Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter"),Job= c("CEO","CEO","Member of the Board","Member of the Board","CEO","CEO","CEO","CEO"))
```

Already tried to merge but results were messy.

Thanks

Comment: I'll mark them, tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is commonly called a "join", "merge" or "appending" data. R wouldn't be much of a language if you couldn't do that!

The field that is matched on is called a "key".  In this case, R assumes your key is `Company`, because it is the only field they have in common.

```
Jobs <- data.frame(Company = c("A","B"), Name = c("Peter","Peter"), Job = c("CEO","Member of the Board"))

Media_Appearence <- data.frame(Company = c("A","A","B","B","A","A","A","A"),Name = c("Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter","Peter"))

merge(Media_Appearence, Jobs)
```

> ```
>   Company  Name                 Job
> 1       A Peter                 CEO
> 2       A Peter                 CEO
> 3       A Peter                 CEO
> 4       A Peter                 CEO
> 5       A Peter                 CEO
> 6       A Peter                 CEO
> 7       B Peter Member of the Board
> 8       B Peter Member of the Board
> ```

You may have noticed that your data was sorted for you. It was sorted by the default key, which in this case is `Company`.

Answer (score 1):

By using match , would not change the original order of data.frame

```
Media_Appearence$Job=Jobs$Job[match(Media_Appearence$Company, Jobs$Company)]
Media_Appearence
  Company  Name                 Job
1       A Peter                 CEO
2       A Peter                 CEO
3       B Peter Member of the Board
4       B Peter Member of the Board
5       A Peter                 CEO
6       A Peter                 CEO
7       A Peter                 CEO
8       A Peter                 CEO
```

Comment: That's another good way

Comment: I was wondering if the column name had names other than Peter it would work.

Comment: @Malakias what I usually to do is paste multiple columns to one for your case, Jobs['New']=paste(Jobs$Company,Jobs$name)